# How to read RAM of embedded system?

Tags: embedded

I have working device, that operates with RAM (random access memory). I want to grab RAM dump. I think it must be a hardware option. Is there a way to do this? Maybe anybody have some expirience?

Comment: What OS?  What chipset?  I'm afraid this question might be too broad.

Comment: OS is Linux. But I haven't access to OS.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to get access to the OS to run your code to dump the RAM (could be as simple as `dd if=/dev/mem of=/tmp/ramdump`). There may be hardware workarounds to get the data directly from the RAM chips or logic traces but they likely involve multi-K$ professional logic analyzers or testing tools. In any case, you gave us too little information for a really useful answer.